# ProgressBar is not animating when data is loading; and loading doesn't wait when using await

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, progress-bar, async-await

In my app data needs to be loaded from a database.  During this time there is a Splash screen that is being displayed.  I would like to have a progress bar animate so added this to the splash screen xaml;

```
<ProgressBar Margin="5" DockPanel.Dock="Top" IsIndeterminate="True"  />
```

This works being but the animation basically stops on every long retrieve of data.  My load data looks something like this;

```
private void loadData()
{
    getData1FromDB();
    displayData1_OnScreen();
    getData2FromDB();
    displayData2_OnScreen();
    getData3FromDB();
    displayData3_OnScreen();
}
```

So when `getData1FromDB()` is running the progress bar animation stops.  Figured the problem could be solved like;

```
private async void loadData()
{
   await Task.Run(() => getData1FromDB());
   displayData1_OnScreen();
   getData2FromDB();
   await Task.Run(() => displayData2_OnScreen());
   getData3FromDB();
   await Task.Run(() => displayData3_OnScreen());
}
```

This caused a different issue.  While `getData1FromDB()` was running the program went onto `displayData1_OnScreen`.  Since `getData1FromDB()` was not done no data was displayed.

How do I solve this without rewriting my entire loading procedure?

edit:  based on the comments;

Nothing else is is calling `displayData1_OnScreen` and to be honest I was surprised too.  The only thing I can think of is that `loadData()` is being called from the constructor.

To be honest no, I am not sure this is where the issue lies.  I am trying to put more debugging in to see what is actually happening after @BradleyDotNET brought it up.

For the question on `getData1FromDB` that is a bit hard to break out.  basically it builds a sqlCMD string based on parameter set and then runs it like this;

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string ConString = ConnectionString();
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConString))
{
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlCMD, con);
    con.Open();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
}
return dt;
```

Comment: You found the first issue (that the UI was being blocked) I'm surprised `displayData1_OnScreen` ran before the await call returned. Does anything else call that function? Are you sure thats where the issue lies.

Comment: There are actually two questions here.. the second is more interesting.. and it's hard trying to capture [both] in the title.. bite-sizes are easier to deal with on SO.

Comment: Could you post also getData1FromDB code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, the following repro attempt seems to do what you want even if loadData() runs in the constructor -

CS:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfAsyncAwaitProgressbar
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new TestViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public TestViewModel()
        {
            Text1 = Text2 = Text3 = "Loading ...";
            loadData();
        }

        public string Text1 { get; private set; }
        public string Text2 { get; private set; }
        public string Text3 { get; private set; }

        public Visibility ProgressbarVisibility { get; private set; }

        private async void loadData()
        {
            setBusyMode(true);
            await Task.Run(() => getData1FromDB());
            await Task.Run(() => getData2FromDB());
            await Task.Run(() => getData3FromDB());
            setBusyMode(false);
        }

        private void getData1FromDB()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Text1 = "Data Result 1";
            raisePropertyChanged(() => Text1);
        }

        private void getData2FromDB()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Text2 = "Data Result 2";
            raisePropertyChanged(() => Text2);
        }

        private void getData3FromDB()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Text3 = "Data Result 3";
            raisePropertyChanged(() => Text3);
        }

        private void setBusyMode(bool isBusy)
        {
            ProgressbarVisibility = isBusy ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
            raisePropertyChanged(() => ProgressbarVisibility);
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void raisePropertyChanged<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> projection)
        {
            var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)projection.Body;
            raisePropertyChanged(memberExpression.Member.Name);
        }

        private void raisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAsyncAwaitProgressbar.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text1}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text2}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text3}"/>
        <ProgressBar Visibility="{Binding ProgressbarVisibility}"
                     IsIndeterminate="True"
                     Height="10"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You should not use async void, except event handlers: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Tip-1-Async-void-is-for-top-level-event-handlers-only
2. There are animations in wpf, that can run on graphic card even when UI thread is blocked, but they are very limited and I woudnt relly on them

What about this code?

```
private async Task loadData()
{
   await Task.Run(getData1FromDB);
   displayData1_OnScreen();

   await Task.Run(getData2FromDB);
   displayData2_OnScreen();

   await Task.Run(getData3FromDB);
   displayData3_OnScreen();
}
```

Comment: Nope, he made some mistakes. First, he used async void. Second he is calling getData2FromDB and getData3FromDB in UI thread but displayData2_OnScreen in async thread, which does not make sense

Comment: If the method *is* a top level method then it being `void` is appropriate.  Either way, that wouldn't cause his problems.  As for the rest of the method; it's erroring before it even reaches that point, so that's clearly not addressing whatever problem is described in the question.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I would remove my answer, but I think there are still some usefull valid points